# How do I style a GeoTIFF correctly in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I downloaded the bathymetric data from GEBCO in geotiff format. When I load it in QGIS, the image is just completely grey. I am using QGIS 2.8.

How I can visualize this data in QGIS?

Comment: Hi ANILDO and welcome to GIS.SE.  Could you expand the question title to give more information about your problem. Also it would help a lot if you could upload an image of what your geotiff looks like.

Comment: Probably you'll need to scale the results.

Answer (score 4):

Once your geotiff is loaded into QGIS, right click on the image in the layers list, select properties.

In 'Render type' select 'Singleband pseudocolor', then in the box on the right, choose a colour map you like the look of, and click on 'Classify'. You can tweak other settings here to get the desired affect e.g. manually changing the range of each colour value, and/or adding more colour classes.

Comment: As an addition, you might check `Min/max` and `Actual (slower)` from the `Load min/max values` section, the press `Load` and `Classify`. Otherwise the colour ramp is spread between 2% and 98% of the values. And you might set an additional nodata value in the transparency tab as well if necessary.